# How to take out the toilet water inlet faucet knob

Tags: plumbing, toilet, faucet

The water inlet got stuck with no incoming water. Suspected it's fully blocked by sand and mud. It's with slow water ingress before but still works. The knob is without screw at the top. Could anyone advise how to take out the knob in order to take out the ceramic cartridge, I think it is, apart for cleaning?

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you should turn off the supply water and install a complete new valve. In my area (obviously not the same as *your* area) these valves are not often repaired, just replaced.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks your reply. As this type of faucet is out of the market and I don't want to replace the whole kit. Prefer to replace it and finally I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed it. I used a big flat screw driver to pry the knob off. One step for a quarter turn. The knob is loosened in about two full turns. Then, use a spanner to remove the nickel painted copper cap that holds the faucet filter cartridge. Once removed the cartridge with a pliers, the dirt and mud is draining out. The cartridge is full of mud. I cleaned up before putting it back to the shelf to remove the faucet.

[image]